# is there some java code testing or practice tool?

Tags: java

Is there some graphical java code testing or practice tool. Let's say I have below code (for example) and I wanted to see quickly what outputs instead of using heavy IDE such as netbeans or eclips:

```
for(int i = 1; i <=100; i++)  
{  
    // print i  
}
```

Is there any *graphical* java quick code testing tool out there ?

---

## Update

Ok I've found [DrJava](http://www.drjava.org/) tool that compiles and runs java code quickly so I can test some java code quickly and easily.

Comment: how can you expect to see the output without a mechanism executing the code statement by statement?

Comment: Command-line execution and `System.out.println`?

Comment: @Juvanis: I don't know what you are saying. If there is some tool to test java code, it would print result of `i` hundred times.

Comment: A debugger provides good "java code testing" and an IDE is an adequate "practice tool". Use Netbeans and get used to the weight.

Comment: Not posting this as an answer, because 1. recommendation questions are off-topic for Stackoverflow and 2. I have no idea whether it's the best available one, but I personally use http://www.jdoodle.com/ or  http://ideone.com/ for testing small programs.

Comment: use command prompt, this will be quickly

Comment: @kviiri: Thanks for pointing out jdoodle.com, it seems good, would have been great if there was such sofware to be used even offline not a website. Thanks anyways

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should go to [ideone.com](http://ideone.com/) or
[compileonline.com](http://www.compileonline.com/compile_java_online.php)

Comment: As an alternative there is http://www.jdoodle.com/

Comment: Thanks but I found DrJava: http://www.drjava.org/

Answer (score 1):

There is...

...it's called Netbeans and Eclipse.

Why don't you want to use the IDEs? If you really want to you can use command line ant and java to build and run things but really IDEs were developed for a reason...

Something that may be useful for you is that you can throw any number of .java files into a project in Netbeans, give them all a main() method and run whichever file you like by right clicking on that file and selecting debug.

Now you get all the proper build/run/debug/etc tools but without the overhead of creating a project for every file.

Comment: There many cases when u need quickly check idea and share it with others.

Comment: In which case you can send them the .java file and they can throw them into whatever IDE they choose. You can throw any number of .java files into a project in Netbeans, give them all a main() method and run whichever file you like by right clicking and selecting debug.

Comment: When u ask question at stackoverflow its very nice to share code on ideone (or JSFiddle in case of javascript) so people can immediately dive in to code without asking additional questions.

Answer (score 1):

Like Simeon said, System.out.println(i);

Then go to your terminal window and type

```
javac MyFileName.java
java MyFilename
```

That will give you the output you need.  Replace "MyFileName" with the name of your file.

Comment: To get the terminal window in windows go to Start > Run > type: cmd. That will bring up the MSDOS environment and you can run your files.  If you get an error that javac is not a recognized command you need to setup your java environment first.